# A Django query to find top 3 posts with maximum comments

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

how can i find the top 3 blogpost with the maximum comments
here are my models:

```
 class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
```

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('BlogPost', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Post your models code clearly and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Post all your models to us help you. but this link should help you https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/duplicate.html

Comment: What do you mean by the maximum comments?

Comment: each post can have n comments so I want to find the top 3 post with the highest no. of comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the top 3 `posts` along with number of comments (`dcount`) grouped by `posts`.

```
from django.db.models import Count

Comments.objects.values('post').annotate(dcount=Count('id')).order_by('-dcount')[:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Count

BlogPost.post_set.values('comment').annotate(comment_count=Count('comment'))
```

Try this and check if will return something.

Edit 1:

Try this instead

```
posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
relation = []
for post in posts:
    post_number = len(list(post.post_set.all()))
    relation.append({'post': post, 'post_number': post_number})
```

Comment: you can try on the shell """python manage.py shell""". Import your models and import Count

Comment: returns all the comments instead.

Comment: This will just return all the comments

Comment: You can send here the return?

Comment: ```<QuerySet [{'comment': 'awesome', 'comment_count': 1}, {'comment': 'awesomeeeee i love it', 'comment_count': 1}, {'comment': 'okaay check', 'comment_count': 1}, {'comment': 'okay', 'comment_count': 1}, {'comment': 'test', 'comment_count': 1}]>```           also using post_set gives Attribute error

Comment: returns this 'BlogPost' object has no attribute 'post_set'

Comment: Try Ram answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against using [**`.values(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values), since then you no longer work with `Post` objects, but with dictionaries. You can use:

```
from django.db.models import Count

BlogPost.objects.alias(
    num_comments=Count('Comments')
).order_by('-num_comments')[:3]
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Comment` instead of <s>`Comments`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Specifying [**`null=False`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) is not necessary: fields are by default not NULLable.